# Error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' (Django + React + Webpack)

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack, django-templates

I was following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/uva-mobile-devhub/set-up-react-in-your-django-project-with-webpack-4fe1f8455396) to set up Django to serve templates with webpack-generated bundles. I have set it up just like in the tutorial. However the problem is when i go to `localhost:8000` I get  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` exception when I open the console in chrome devtools. Other html I put in the template file gets rendered except the reactjs bundle. My folder structure is as follows:

```
.
├── djangoapp
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── djangoapp
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── reactapp
│   │   └── static
│   │       ├── bundles
│   │       │   └── main-fdf4c969af981093661f.js
│   │       └── js
│   │           └── index.jsx
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── webpack-stats.json
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'webpack_loader'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
    }
}

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,

  entry: './djangoapp/reactapp/static/js/index.jsx', 

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./djangoapp/reactapp/static/bundles/'),
      filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new BundleTracker({filename: './djangoapp/webpack-stats.json'}),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: ['babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/},
      { test: /\.jsx$/, use: ['babel-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/}
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },


};
```

templates/index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="react"></div>
 {% render_bundle 'main' %}
 </body>
</html>
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-env", "react"]
}
```

The exception is thrown at the start of line 1 of the `main-fdf4c969af981093661f.js` file, on the opening tag of  `<!DOCTYPE html>` element. My guess is that the browser expects javascript code, but instead it is given html. Also, I don't understand how does Django know where to look for the bundles since I didn't specify the root (the `reactapp` directory) of the `static/bundles` anywhere.

Comment: Not sure if thats the problem but you should write "env" and not "babel-preset-env" as the preset in .babelrc

Comment: @MatanBobi You're right, but this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after a while by adding the following code to `settings.py`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   ('bundles', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'reactapp/bundles'))
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

I also had to change `STATIC_URL` to `/static/`.

This is how it is supposed to work:

- Webpack generates bundles to the `reactapp/bundles` folder.
- When Django server is running it scans changes inside `reactapp/bundles` and 
  after each new change copies the contents of the folder to the root `djangoapp/static/` folder as defined by `STATIC_ROOT` setting.
- After that the files inside `STATIC_ROOT` can be accessed by browser through the `STATIC_URL` like this: `localhost:8000/static/bundles/<bundle>`. It would normally default to `localhost:8000/static/<bundle>` but the first element of the tuple inside `STATICFILES_DIRS` explicitly tells Django to copy the contents inside `static/bundles` directory.
- Django then automatically generates links to static files when serving a page.

**NOTE:** `STATIC_URL` should be prepended with a `/` otherwise the static path would be appended to the current page link instead of the root. E.g on the `/index` page the link to the static file would be `localhost:8000/index/static/...` instead of `localhost:8000/static`, which would be wrong and would result in `404 not found`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one! Everything seems to followed perfectly. First, please ensure `django-webpack-loader` is installed as expected. Second, your concern seems to be valid, we would have to tell django where exactly to look for bundles as by default it uses `STATIC_URL + bundle_name` (as suggested in documentation at http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/). Try adding `publicPath` to `webpack.config.js` as:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve('./djangoapp/reactapp/static/bundles/'),
  filename: "[name]-[hash].js",
  publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/<path to bundles>"
},
```

I am not sure if it would work, but let me know if it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work. [Webpack documentation](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) says `publicPath` is only useful when you host the bundles on a different domain. Anyway I tried replacing `{% render_bundle 'name' %}` with `<script type="text/javascript" src="/reactapp/static/bundles/main-fdf4c969af981093661f.js"></script>` but still no success. Same error.